# Drop-down menu with autofilter and click/enter for selection and navigation by mouse/arrow keys

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code that retrieves categories from DB and act as dynamic category search. I kindly ask you to review my code and tell me if the code can be optimized/improved. Thank you for your help.

This is the html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
  }
  #myInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  #myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .show {display: block;}
  .selected {
    background:#efefef;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>
  <input name="cat" id="test" type="text" placeholder="220" value="" readonly="readonly" size="4">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="loadXmlDoc(0)" class="dropbtn"><span id="categoriego">Dropdown</span></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Cauta..." id="cautare" oninput="filterFunction()">
      <span id="innermenu"></span>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <script>
  rezultat=[];
  filteredarr = [];
  flag=0;
  gos=0;
  cautare = document.getElementById("cautare");
  innermenu = document.getElementById("innermenu");
  myDropdown=document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  categoriego=document.getElementById("categoriego");
  test=document.getElementById("test");
  async function loadXmlDoc(cat){
    let reposResponse = await fetch(`post.php?cat=`+cat);
    rezultat = await reposResponse.json();
    var eacha=[];
    for (i = 0; i < rezultat.length; i++) {
      eacha[i] = "<a id="+ i +">"+rezultat[i][1]+"("+rezultat[i][0]+")"+"</a>";
    }
    cautare.value="";
    innermenu.innerHTML=eacha.join("");
    myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
    cautare.focus();
    flag=0;
    document.getElementById(0).style.background = "#ddd";
  }
  function filterFunction(){
    var eachb=[];
    filteredarr = [];
    counter=0;
    filter = cautare.value.toUpperCase();
    for (i = 0; i < rezultat.length; i++) {
      defiltrat=rezultat[i][0]+rezultat[i][1];
      if (defiltrat.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        eachb[i] = "<a id="+counter+">"+rezultat[i][1]+"("+rezultat[i][0]+")"+"</a>";
        filteredarr.push([rezultat[i][0],rezultat[i][1]]);
        counter++;
        flag=1;
        gos=0;
      }
    }
    innermenu.innerHTML=eachb.join("");
    document.getElementById(0).style.background = "#ddd";
  }
  innermenu.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
    lennt=rezultat;
    if(flag==1){
      lennt=filteredarr;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < lennt.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(i).style.background = "";
    }
    gos=e.target.id;
    document.getElementById(gos).style.background = "#ddd";
  }, false);
  innermenu.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    lennt=rezultat;
    if(flag==1){
      lennt=filteredarr;
    }
    myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
    categoriego.innerHTML=lennt[gos][1];
    test.value=lennt[gos][0];
    gos=0;
  }, false);
  cautare.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    document.getElementById(gos).style.background = "";
    lennt=rezultat;
    if(flag==1){
      lennt=filteredarr;
    }
    if(e.which == 38){
      gos--;
      if(gos<0)
      {
        gos=0;
      }
    }
    if(e.which == 40){
      gos++;
      if(gos==lennt.length)
      {
        gos=lennt.length-1;
      }
    }
    if(e.which == 13){
      categoriego.innerHTML=lennt[gos][1];
      myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
      test.value=lennt[gos][0];
      gos=0;
    }
    document.getElementById(gos).style.background = "#ddd";
    console.log(gos);
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the post.php for testing purposes

```
<?php
$cars = array
 (
 array(55,"Volvo"),
 array(42,"BMW"),
 array(13,"Saab"),
 array(71,"Renault"),
 array(88,"Toyota"),
 array(99,"Peugeot"),
 array(21,"Land Rover")
);
echo json_encode($cars);
?>
```

Comment: Please use one language, either romanian either english. And for next posts try to use english, will be more easier for the reviewers to read the variables and understand what are you trying to do. :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.